# asp.net 6 middleware to overwrite response from another middleware using pipe

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have middlewareA, which has to read response from another middlewareB an based on some condition overwrite/discard response from middleware and send some custom response.
middelwareA also adds some response headers.

Based on documentation, recommendation is to use Pipe instead of Stream, but all examples are for reading from request as pipe. how can middleware read from response with Pipe?

for setting response headers i am using context.Response.OnStarting in middlewareA, who/where should i add code to read response as stream/pipe

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when you want set response header in middleware pipeline 'out' procedure. It is said that you cannot modify the header after `await next.invoke()` method [officially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication). Or you will get exception.

The workaroud is using call back of `Response.OnStarting`  before `await next.invoke()`

```
            httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
```

You can try the following code.

middlewareA.cs

```
    public class middlewareA
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public middlewareA(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A before await");
            httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine("A on response start");

                if (httpContext.Response.Headers["headerB"]== "BBB")
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("headerA", "headerB has been set");
                }
                else
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("headerB", "headerB not set");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await _next(httpContext);
            Console.WriteLine("A after await");

        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.  
    public static class middlewareAExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UsemiddlewareA(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<middlewareA>();
        }
    }
```

middlewareB.cs

```
    public class middlewareB
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public middlewareB(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B before await");
            httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine("B on response start");
                httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("headerB","BBB");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await _next(httpContext);
            Console.WriteLine("B after await");

        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.  
    public static class middlewareBExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UsemiddlewareB(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<middlewareB>();
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
app.MapControllers();
app.UsemiddlewareA();
app.UsemiddlewareB();
app.Run();
```

The console output
[image]

The browser network
[image]

Comment: thanks Quiang for reply. I was looking for how to middelwareA can read response from middleware and then overwrite that response to client.